# Magento2 :getting empty customer grid with No Such Entity message after migration

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, customer-grid, data-migration

After migration from Magento 1.9 to 2.1.6, I am getting empty Customer Grid in Admin Panel with No Such Entity message. I can see the customer data in customer_entity table, but grid show No such entity. I have reset and reindexes, but still same issue.
Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

open  vendor\magento\framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException.php

put this code in constructor method

```
$trace = debug_backtrace();
  var_dump($trace[1]['class'] . '::' . $trace[1]['function'] . '('.$trace[1]['line'] .')';
die();
```

After refresh your customer grid you find error related website repository.

your solution is go to table store_group in your magento 2 database and remove all group expected "Default" and "Main Website Store" and check your issue has been fix.

Comment: Thanks Pratik, this approach has helped in reaching solution. It was a migration from multi-store to single store, so assigning all the customers to single website has helped in resolving this issue. Thanks very much Pratik for the help.

Comment: @AmitDS please accept answer so some other people help this post.